Displacing End of a Curved Beam Flexure and Calculating Elastic Force

Hi everyone! I have a flexure mechanism that I'm trying to use as a spring. It's essentially a curved beam. The curved beam starts with radius of curvature $r_0$ at rest (no force being generated). The left end of the curved beam is pinned at $x=0$.  The right end is freely moving, but the end stays on the x-axis for all deformation. The beam's right end is then shifted to the left by $x_d$, causing the beam to bow upwards and a bending moment across the beam to be generated. The beam hence acts like a spring that creates generates a horizontal force $F$ acting along the x-axis, pointing away from the origin at $x=0$.
How is this force F related to $x_d$? Let's say I know the final radius of curvature $r_f$ and the arc length of the beam $L$, which stays constant throughout. Use any variables you need, such as the modulus of elasticity, beam cross section dimensions, etc.
I've looked online for help but most examples seem to deal with forces in the y-direction, and never with a beam that is curved at rest. ChatGPT said $F = \frac{EI}{r_0^2}x_d$, but I'm skeptical with ChatGPT and wanted to ask here. Thanks!
